# How to Link with g++ against libraries with build numbers

Tags: g++

how can I set up to link against a library with different build numbers.

I have program Flyer and I have two libraries, libTest.so.33 and libTest.so.33.2.1

I want to compile two different installs.  One with libTest.so.33 and one with libTest.so.33.2.1

In my config file i have LIBS += lTest

How can I set up my config so I can compile against the "33.2.1" one?

I tried LIBS += -lTest.so.33.2.1  But that threw an error.

I also tried LIBS += /pathtofile/libTest.so.33.2.1  which compiled, but after running a ldd on my program it was linked to the libTest.so.33

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure these are two different libraries? Have you read [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)?